# Reading .env file parameters from application.yml in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

I use some sensitive data by passing as environment variables via IntelliJ run config:

```
spring:
...
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${DB_NAME}
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

However, I am wondering if it is possible to read from `.env` file and match these labels without passing them via IntelliJ or command line. In `docker-compose` it is possible using `env_file` parameter as far as I remember. Is there a similar thing for application properties to read and match parameters in `.env` file by giving its location?

Comment: That are the supported ways:https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Comment: I could not see anything related to `.env` file on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you put the `.env` file in the top of the project directory, you can add the following configuration to read variables from the `.env` file

```
...
spring:
    config:
        import: optional:file:.env[.properties]
...
```

Comment: Thanks for help. What is the `optional` and `[.properties]` parameters? And what if `application.yml` and `.env` files are different locations? I mean is this approach always assume the .env file s in the project root?

Comment: If it is located elsewhere, you can use absolute path for configuration. The [.properties] is a hint for spring which translates to “Use this file without an extension as a .properties file.”

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not supported. I would say, it's not a job of Spring Boot to read `.env` files.
It's a job of your shell environment (i.e. `bash`, `zsh`) or a job of your IDE (there are [corresponding plugins for Intellij](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=androidstudio&products=appcode&products=aqua&products=clion&products=dataspell&products=dbe&products=go&products=idea&products=idea_ce&products=idea_edu&products=mps&products=phpstorm&products=pycharm&products=pycharm_ce&products=pycharm_edu&products=rider&products=ruby&products=webstorm&search=.env))

But as I can see you do some unnecessary work by introducing your own env variables and mapping them to Spring Boot properties.
It's unnecessary, because the value for each Spring Boot property can be passed and recognized with a corresponding uppercased environment variable (see [this docs section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.4/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables)). This means that if you want to pass a value for `spring.datasource.password` property to Spring Boot, you can just start the app with a value in `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD` environment variable.

Also, I do not see any reasons to use `.env` file while developing apps with Spring Boot. In your `src/resources/application.yaml` just set `spring.profiles.active: secrets` and put your sensitive data (which you do not want to commit) into `application-secrets.yaml` (which is `.gitignore`d to avoid accidental commit)

Please note that ideally you also should not keep secrets in a file when deploying your app. You should inject them [as environment variable](https://12factor.net/config) on startup of your application's process, so it would only exist in a memory of a working process.